# Abstracting change tracking on entities

Tags: entity-framework, architecture

Just something I was wondering, and whether it makes sense. So we're using EntityFramework and obviously its change tracking capability allows for us to determine if a property has changed or not. It seems the change tracking is tightly coupled to EF, and for me to get to this information, I need to use EF classes, and I don't want to be referencing EF in business layer libraries. So would I need to provide methods on my Repository interfaces to get to these changes? Do i provide "metadata" on my poco objects with this info? Just trying to find a clean solution for this.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you provide some more info on what type of information you need from the change tracker and what it will be used for?

Comment: So my thinking was I may need the previous and new value of a property in my business layer to determine if that particular property has changed for instance, and I know with EF one can determine that on the entity by getting the DbEntityEntry for that entity, but as mentioned, I don't want my business layer knowing anything about EF (i.e. not referencing any EF dlls), and just wondered if there is some pattern out there that perhaps would help with this.

Comment: I suppose it depends on your infrastructure. Are you needing the values for auditing? You could do everything inside your implemented version of the DBContext within the SaveChanges method. Inside that method you will have access to the entries and the change tracker.